# ListItemButton as NavLink - apply style when active/selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have list of NavLinks:

```
const users = Array.from(Array(5).keys()).map((key) => ({
    id: key,
    name: `User ${key}`,
}));

<List>
{users.map((user) => {
    return (
        <ListItem disablePadding key={user.id}>
            <ListItemButton
                component={NavLink}
                to={`/messages/${user.id}`}
                sx={{
                    "&.active": {
                        backgroundColor: "lightgray",
                    },
                }}
            >
                <ListItemIcon>
                    <PersonIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={user.name}></ListItemText>
            </ListItemButton>
        </ListItem>
    );
})}
</List>
```

The problem is that I have to manually specify the style of active link and hardcode `backgroundColor`. When I remove `sx` style from the component, link doesn't look like it's active. Why it doesn't automatically change the background color when active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListItemButton` extends the base button component, neither of which have any default styling for an added `"active"` CSS classname. When *actually* rendering the `NavLink` component *as* the `ListItemButton.component` then the `NavLink` component applies a `"active"` class, but the default link styling is overridden/set by the base button and `ListItemButton` styling.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)

> ***By default, an `active` class is added to a `<NavLink>` component when it
> is active.*** This provides the same simple styling mechanism for most
> users who are upgrading from v5. One difference as of `v6.0.0-beta.3` is
> that `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` have been removed from
> `NavLinkProps`. Instead, you can pass a function to either `style` or
> `className` that will allow you to customize the inline styling or the
> class string based on the component's active state.

The default background color is `"transparent"`, and the `"active"` is overriding it.

[image]

The `ListItemButton`'s `sx` prop is setting the styling for the `"active"` class and has higher CSS selector specificity.

An alternative way to apply CSS for the `ListItemButton`/`NavLink` is to use the `NavLink`'s `style` function prop:

```
<List>
  {users.map((user) => {
    return (
      <ListItem disablePadding key={user.id}>
        <ListItemButton
          component={NavLink}
          to={`/messages/${user.id}`}
          style={({ isActive }) => isActive ? {
            backgroundColor: "lightgray"
          } : null}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>
              <PersonIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={user.name}></ListItemText>
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
    );
  })}
</List>
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! However the `style` function prop doesn't work for me, it gives me compilation error `No overload matches this call.`. I'll stick with `sx` approach.

Comment: @Signum I think that issue occurs when you are using Typescript. It's because the `ListItemButton` props are not expecting a `style` prop to be a function. Either way, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: you can use sx instead of style: `sx={{ "&.active": { background: "lightgrey" } }}`